# Run-time check failure - variable being used without being initialized

Tags: c++, c

My code below is producing this error:

> Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'IBlockObject' is being used without being initialized

I am really stuck on this. I know there is an initialization problem, but I don't know how to resolve it. Here is the code:

```
typedef struct{ //ISTATUS Structure
    long statusBit;
}ISTATUS;

typedef struct{ // INODE Structure
    char fileName[20];
    long INodeNumber;
    long BlockAddress;
    long NextINodeAddress;
}INODE;

typedef struct{ //IBLOCK Structure
    long BlockNumber;
}IBLOCK;

ISTATUS IStatusObject;
INODE INodeObject;
IBLOCK IBlockObject;


InitializeStructures(IStatusObject, INodeObject, IBlockObject);
```

Comment: Why did you mark this as 3 languages? Are you honestly trying to compile this same exact code in compilers for three different languages? And you should show the signature of `InitializeStructures`.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume you mean C++, and I'll assume the the signature of `InitializeStructures` is:

```
void InitializeStructres(ISTATUS a, INODE b, IBLOCK c)
```

The issue is you are passing the objects by *value*. `InitializeStructures` will get its own copy of these objects you are passing in, and anything `InitializeStructures` does will not be reflected on the objects you passed in.

This will cause the error, because of the copy operation. You are attempting to copy an object ("using" the object) without having initialized it.

I assume you want to make the function signature as follows:

```
void InitializeStructres(ISTATUS& a, INODE& b, IBLOCK& c)
```

So that `InitializeStructures` does *not* copy the objects; instead it will operate directly on the objects passed in by reference.

Quick note: your type / variable naming is really not standard. Names like `IStatusObject` are usually interfaces (for example `IUnknown`). And all-uppercase names are usually legacy or C symbols.

Comment: I really appreciate your help but this thing could solve the problem Visual Studio gives me syntax error